# How to explore a folder from res and choose some content?

Tags: android, android-resources, imageicon

Imagine you want to set a picture for your profile, applications lets you to open your gallery or take a picture. BUT in my case I want to let user to select a picture from a set of images which I have designed already, then I want my app to pop up a window which contains image set and let user to browse between them and finally select one.
What is the best practice to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where u want to store the image selected?

Comment: I want to use it inside application for user icon, I don't know where it may save, maybe in drawable

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors did you get?

Comment: I tried this: 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String path = "/res/raw"
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(intent);
and corresponding error was:
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT dat=android.resource://com.toosfuse.listview/2131427328 typ=*/* }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all Drawable resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921927/how-to-get-all-drawable-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem using a combination of [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and intent concept (startActivityForResult). In my solution I have created a GridView and put my images in an Integer array, one by one; then my gridView displays items and after I select one image, it sends result to Main Activity.